# Subset dataframe where date is within x days of a vector of dates in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, subset

I have a vector of dates e.g.

```
dates <- c('2013-01-01', '2013-04-02', '2013-06-10', '2013-09-30')
```

And a dataframe which contains a date column e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(
                'date' = c('2013-01-04', '2013-01-22', '2013-10-01', '2013-10-10'),
                'a'    = c(1,2,3,4),
                'b'    = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
                )
```

And I would would like to subset the dataframe so it only contains rows where the date is less than 5 days after any of the dates in the 'dates' vector.

i.e. The initial dataframe looks like this

```
date       a b 
2013-01-04 1 a
2013-01-22 2 b
2013-10-01 3 c
2013-10-10 4 d
```

After the query I would only be left with the first and third row (since 2013-01-04 is within 5 days of 2013-01-01 and 2013-10-01 is within 5 days of 2013-09-30)

Does anyone know of the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `df$date %in% dates`.

Comment: @Roman, the OP is looking for a range relative to dates

Comment: @RicardoSaporta doh, senior moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy (and very fast) to do with a `data.table` roll:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

# convert to Date (or IDate) to have numbers instead of strings for dates
# also set the key for dates for the join
dt[, date := as.Date(date)]
dates = data.table(date = as.Date(dates), key = 'date')

# join with a roll of 5 days, throwing out dates that don't match
dates[dt, roll = 5, nomatch = 0]
#         date a b
#1: 2013-01-04 1 a
#2: 2013-10-01 3 c
```

Comment: Thanks, I have begun to use data tables more and know how good they can be so this looks like it may be the best and quic kest way of doing it however copying your code exactly (and my set up above) returns an empty data table for me... Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: @user1165199 you're getting an empty `data.table` with example in OP? that's very strange - maybe restart your session in case you overwrote smth?

Comment: It is still empty, however when I increase roll to be something massive (10000000000) it returns all rows. Could it be that my dates are stored as datetime or something and it is adding on 5 seconds instead of 5 days?

Comment: @user1165199 `as.Date` should convert anything to a date, it can't have time, I suggest `dput`'ing a tiny part of your data (or a more representative sample since it sounds like OP isn't). You can also try `as.IDate` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of data.table and it works now, not sure what the issue was before... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

#### broken down into steps:

```
# Rows Selected: Iterate over each row in the DF, 
#   and check if its `date` value is within 5 from any value in the `dates` vector
rows <- sapply(df$date, function(x) any( abs(x-dates) <=  5))

# Use that result to subset your data.frame
df[rows, ]

#         date a b
# 1 2013-01-04 1 a
# 3 2013-10-01 3 c
```

Importantly, **make sure your date values are actual `Date`s and not `character`s looking like dates**

```
dates <- as.Date(dates)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `df$date` is of class date. Then:

```
df[df$date %in% sapply(dates, function(x) x:(x+5)),]

        date a b
1 2013-01-04 1 a
3 2013-10-01 3 c
```

For some reason I feel like this may be a more proper method:

```
 df[df$date %in% mapply(`:`, from=dates, to=dates+5),]
```

Comment: just use `abs` ;)   A lot less searching and iterating

Comment: @RicardoSaporta I think the OP asked for only 5 days after

Comment: To be fair, OP has two different wordings of his desired range that make it unclear. In any case, @RicardoSaporta's method of directly subtracting `dates` from `df$dates` should do better in most cases - although I'd be curious to see if/when this method would be better.

Comment: Personally, I prefer @eddi's method, but of course I would :)   I do however, think it is important for a user to understand what is going and how to make it happen