# Selecting a specific range of days prior to event in R

Tags: r

I have been learning r for a few days, and I am trying to do a specific output and I can not figure out how to select days prior to an event.

I am trying to determine how recharge events impact detections of a containment in water samples. I have data that has 7 columns (Date, month, day, year, samp, prcip, snow) where the date is YYYY/MM/DD, month, day, and year are what they say, samp has a 0, 1, or NA, and both precip and snow have daily totals for either rain or snow. There is 1 row for each day.

I want to explore rain events for different number of days prior to a sampling event. I would like to select the rows with either a 0 (sample and no detection) or 1 (sample with detection) and then select a number of days prior, say 5 for this example, and compare the mean, sum, etc of those prior days between the 0 and 1 groups.

I have found ways to select just the rows, and to get a count of how many consecutive days have either a 0 or a 1 ([How to subset consecutive rows if they meet a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550838/how-to-subset-consecutive-rows-if-they-meet-a-condition)), but I can not figure out how to select a number of days prior to a sampling event and create a new table.

I have over 800 sampling days spread over 20+ years, so I do not want to input each date either ([Subset dataframe where date is within x days of a vector of dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229079/subset-dataframe-where-date-is-within-x-days-of-a-vector-of-dates-in-r)).

I have tried using the %>% pipe, and some other selection methods and have been able to select the rows containing 0 or 1, but I don't understand how to also get the days prior to the sampling day. I am looking for any direction, suggestions, or functions/tools/packages to look up as I have come up short on new avenues to explore.

I would like to select my data so I can eventually run some simple statistics on it. This is an exploratory project for me - to learn r and practice statistics. I would like to run t-tests, and ANOVA, look at different days prior to sampling. I am selecting sample days so I can eventually ask a question such as "how does rainfall 5 days prior to a sampling event impact detections" or "how is the mean of rain 5 days prior to a positive detection different from 5 days before a negative detection". Hopefully giving you context of my purpose helps me to explain myself and what I am looking for.

How my data looks now:

```
date    month   day year    samp    precip  snow
```

`11/11/1988 11  11  1988    NA  0   0
11/12/1988  11  12  1988    NA  0   0
11/13/1988  11  13  1988    NA  0.55    0
11/14/1988  11  14  1988    NA  0   0
11/15/1988  11  15  1988    NA  0   0
11/16/1988  11  16  1988    NA  0.52    0
11/17/1988  11  17  1988    NA  0   0
11/18/1988  11  18  1988    NA  0   0
11/19/1988  11  19  1988    NA  0   0
11/20/1988  11  20  1988    NA  0.39    0
11/21/1988  11  21  1988    NA  0.43    0
11/22/1988  11  22  1988    NA  0   0
11/23/1988  11  23  1988    NA  0   0
11/24/1988  11  24  1988    NA  0   0
11/25/1988  11  25  1988    NA  0   0
11/26/1988  11  26  1988    NA  0.11    0
11/27/1988  11  27  1988    NA  0.08    0
11/28/1988  11  28  1988    NA  0.01    0
11/29/1988  11  29  1988    NA  0   0
11/30/1988  11  30  1988    NA  0   0
12/1/1988   12  1   1988    NA  0   0
12/2/1988   12  2   1988    NA  0   0
12/3/1988   12  3   1988    NA  0   0
12/4/1988   12  4   1988    NA  0   0
12/5/1988   12  5   1988    NA  0   0
12/6/1988   12  6   1988    NA  0   0
12/7/1988   12  7   1988    NA  0   0
12/8/1988   12  8   1988    NA  0   0
12/9/1988   12  9   1988    NA  0   0
12/10/1988  12  10  1988    NA  0   0
12/11/1988  12  11  1988    NA  0   0
12/12/1988  12  12  1988    NA  0   0
12/13/1988  12  13  1988    NA  0.03    1
12/14/1988  12  14  1988    NA  0   0
12/15/1988  12  15  1988    NA  0   0
12/16/1988  12  16  1988    NA  0   0
12/17/1988  12  17  1988    NA  0   2
12/18/1988  12  18  1988    NA  0   0
12/19/1988  12  19  1988    NA  0   0
12/20/1988  12  20  1988    NA  0.07    0
12/21/1988  12  21  1988    NA  0.02    0
12/22/1988  12  22  1988    NA  0   0
12/23/1988  12  23  1988    NA  1.3 0
12/24/1988  12  24  1988    NA  0   0
12/25/1988  12  25  1988    NA  0   0
12/26/1988  12  26  1988    NA  0   0
12/27/1988  12  27  1988    NA  0.85    3
12/28/1988  12  28  1988    NA  0.37    3
12/29/1988  12  29  1988    NA  0   0
12/30/1988  12  30  1988    NA  0   0
12/31/1988  12  31  1988    NA  0   0
1/1/1989    1   1   1989    NA  0   0
1/2/1989    1   2   1989    NA  0   0
1/3/1989    1   3   1989    NA  0   0
1/4/1989    1   4   1989    NA  0   0
1/5/1989    1   5   1989    NA  0   0
1/6/1989    1   6   1989    NA  0.54    0
1/7/1989    1   7   1989    NA  0   0
1/8/1989    1   8   1989    NA  0.08    0
1/9/1989    1   9   1989    NA  0   0
1/10/1989   1   10  1989    NA  0   0
1/11/1989   1   11  1989    NA  0   0
1/12/1989   1   12  1989    NA  0   0
1/13/1989   1   13  1989    NA  0   0
1/14/1989   1   14  1989    NA  0   0
1/15/1989   1   15  1989    NA  0.04    1
1/16/1989   1   16  1989    NA  0   0
1/17/1989   1   17  1989    NA  0   0
1/18/1989   1   18  1989    NA  0   0
1/19/1989   1   19  1989    NA  0   0
1/20/1989   1   20  1989    NA  0   0
1/21/1989   1   21  1989    NA  0   0
1/22/1989   1   22  1989    NA  0   0
1/23/1989   1   23  1989    NA  0   0
1/24/1989   1   24  1989    NA  0   0
1/25/1989   1   25  1989    NA  0   0
1/26/1989   1   26  1989    NA  0.15    0
1/27/1989   1   27  1989    NA  0   0
1/28/1989   1   28  1989    NA  0   0
1/29/1989   1   29  1989    NA  0   0
1/30/1989   1   30  1989    NA  0   0
1/31/1989   1   31  1989    NA  0   0
2/1/1989    2   1   1989    NA  0   0
2/2/1989    2   2   1989    NA  0   0
2/3/1989    2   3   1989    NA  0.01    0
2/4/1989    2   4   1989    NA  0   0
2/5/1989    2   5   1989    NA  0.28    4
2/6/1989    2   6   1989    NA  0.21    3
2/7/1989    2   7   1989    NA  0   0
2/8/1989    2   8   1989    NA  0   0
2/9/1989    2   9   1989    NA  0   0
2/10/1989   2   10  1989    NA  0   0
2/11/1989   2   11  1989    NA  0   0
2/12/1989   2   12  1989    NA  0   0
2/13/1989   2   13  1989    NA  0.26    1
2/14/1989   2   14  1989    NA  0   0
2/15/1989   2   15  1989    NA  0.04    0
2/16/1989   2   16  1989    NA  0.03    1
2/17/1989   2   17  1989    NA  0   0
2/18/1989   2   18  1989    NA  0   0
2/19/1989   2   19  1989    NA  0   0
2/20/1989   2   20  1989    NA  0   0
2/21/1989   2   21  1989    NA  0.21    2
2/22/1989   2   22  1989    NA  0   0
2/23/1989   2   23  1989    NA  0   0
2/24/1989   2   24  1989    NA  0   0
2/25/1989   2   25  1989    NA  0   0
2/26/1989   2   26  1989    NA  0   0
2/27/1989   2   27  1989    NA  0   0
2/28/1989   2   28  1989    NA  0   0
3/1/1989    3   1   1989    1   0   0
3/2/1989    3   2   1989    NA  0   0
3/3/1989    3   3   1989    NA  0   0
3/4/1989    3   4   1989    NA  0   0
3/5/1989    3   5   1989    NA  0.34    0
3/6/1989    3   6   1989    NA  0   0
3/7/1989    3   7   1989    NA  0   0
3/8/1989    3   8   1989    NA  0   0
3/9/1989    3   9   1989    NA  0   0
3/10/1989   3   10  1989    NA  0   0
3/11/1989   3   11  1989    NA  0   0
3/12/1989   3   12  1989    NA  0   0
3/13/1989   3   13  1989    NA  0   0
3/14/1989   3   14  1989    NA  0   0
3/15/1989   3   15  1989    NA  0   0
3/16/1989   3   16  1989    NA  0   0
3/17/1989   3   17  1989    NA  0   0
3/18/1989   3   18  1989    NA  0.02    0
3/19/1989   3   19  1989    NA  0   0
3/20/1989   3   20  1989    NA  0   0
3/21/1989   3   21  1989    NA  0   0
3/22/1989   3   22  1989    NA  0   0
3/23/1989   3   23  1989    NA  0   0
3/24/1989   3   24  1989    NA  0   0
3/25/1989   3   25  1989    NA  0   0
3/26/1989   3   26  1989    NA  0   0
3/27/1989   3   27  1989    NA  0   0
3/28/1989   3   28  1989    NA  0.02    0
3/29/1989   3   29  1989    NA  0.81    0
3/30/1989   3   30  1989    NA  0   0
3/31/1989   3   31  1989    NA  0   0
4/1/1989    4   1   1989    NA  0   0
4/2/1989    4   2   1989    NA  0.05    0
4/3/1989    4   3   1989    NA  0.81    0
4/4/1989    4   4   1989    NA  0.49    0
4/5/1989    4   5   1989    NA  0   0
4/6/1989    4   6   1989    NA  0   0
4/7/1989    4   7   1989    NA  0   0
4/8/1989    4   8   1989    NA  0   0
4/9/1989    4   9   1989    NA  0.26    0
4/10/1989   4   10  1989    NA  0   0
4/11/1989   4   11  1989    NA  0   0
4/12/1989   4   12  1989    NA  0   0
4/13/1989   4   13  1989    NA  0   0
4/14/1989   4   14  1989    NA  0   0
4/15/1989   4   15  1989    NA  0   0
4/16/1989   4   16  1989    NA  0   0
4/17/1989   4   17  1989    NA  0.27    0
4/18/1989   4   18  1989    NA  0.04    0
4/19/1989   4   19  1989    NA  0   0
4/20/1989   4   20  1989    NA  0   0
4/21/1989   4   21  1989    NA  0   0
4/22/1989   4   22  1989    NA  0   0
4/23/1989   4   23  1989    NA  0   0
4/24/1989   4   24  1989    NA  0   0
4/25/1989   4   25  1989    NA  0   0
4/26/1989   4   26  1989    NA  0   0
4/27/1989   4   27  1989    NA  0.23    0
4/28/1989   4   28  1989    NA  0.28    0
4/29/1989   4   29  1989    NA  0   0
4/30/1989   4   30  1989    NA  0   0
5/1/1989    5   1   1989    NA  0   0
5/2/1989    5   2   1989    NA  0   0
5/3/1989    5   3   1989    0   0.28    0
5/4/1989    5   4   1989    NA  0   0
5/5/1989    5   5   1989    NA  0.06    0
5/6/1989    5   6   1989    NA  0   0
5/7/1989    5   7   1989    NA  0   0
5/8/1989    5   8   1989    NA  0   0
5/9/1989    5   9   1989    NA  0.42    0
5/10/1989   5   10  1989    NA  0.02    0
5/11/1989   5   11  1989    NA  0   0
5/12/1989   5   12  1989    NA  0   0
5/13/1989   5   13  1989    NA  0   0
5/14/1989   5   14  1989    NA  0   0
5/15/1989   5   15  1989    NA  0   0
5/16/1989   5   16  1989    NA  0   0
5/17/1989   5   17  1989    NA  0   0
5/18/1989   5   18  1989    NA  0   0
5/19/1989   5   19  1989    NA  0.05    0
5/20/1989   5   20  1989    NA  1.17    0
5/21/1989   5   21  1989    NA  0   0
5/22/1989   5   22  1989    NA  0   0
5/23/1989   5   23  1989    NA  0.03    0
5/24/1989   5   24  1989    NA  0   0
5/25/1989   5   25  1989    NA  0.21    0
5/26/1989   5   26  1989    NA  0.37    0
5/27/1989   5   27  1989    NA  0   0
5/28/1989   5   28  1989    NA  0   0
5/29/1989   5   29  1989    NA  0   0
5/30/1989   5   30  1989    NA  1.5 0
5/31/1989   5   31  1989    NA  0.14    0
6/1/1989    6   1   1989    1   0.97    0
6/2/1989    6   2   1989    NA  1.04    0
6/3/1989    6   3   1989    NA  0   0
6/4/1989    6   4   1989    NA  0.25    0
6/5/1989    6   5   1989    NA  0   0
6/6/1989    6   6   1989    NA  0   0
6/7/1989    6   7   1989    NA  0   0
6/8/1989    6   8   1989    NA  0   0
6/9/1989    6   9   1989    NA  0   0
6/10/1989   6   10  1989    NA  0   0
6/11/1989   6   11  1989    NA  0   0
6/12/1989   6   12  1989    NA  0.32    0
6/13/1989   6   13  1989    NA  0.16    0
6/14/1989   6   14  1989    NA  0   0`

How I would like my data to look once it is completed:

`date   month   day year    samp    precip  snow
2/24/1989   2   24  1989    NA  0   0
2/25/1989   2   25  1989    NA  0   0
2/26/1989   2   26  1989    NA  0   0
2/27/1989   2   27  1989    NA  0   0
2/28/1989   2   28  1989    NA  0   0
3/1/1989    3   1   1989    1   0   0
4/28/1989   4   28  1989    NA  0.28    0
4/29/1989   4   29  1989    NA  0   0
4/30/1989   4   30  1989    NA  0   0
5/1/1989    5   1   1989    NA  0   0
5/2/1989    5   2   1989    NA  0   0
5/3/1989    5   3   1989    0   0.28    0
5/27/1989   5   27  1989    NA  0   0
5/28/1989   5   28  1989    NA  0   0
5/29/1989   5   29  1989    NA  0   0
5/30/1989   5   30  1989    NA  1.5 0
5/31/1989   5   31  1989    NA  0.14    0
6/1/1989    6   1   1989    1   0.97    0`

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you, I would love to have done that, and attempted to do so but I could not get tables to work. I feel so out of my element with all of this but I really am trying. Thank you for your feedback and I will figure out how to provide that and do so later. I was anxious to see if anyone had some quick direction and so gave up on the tables in the question for the moment as I was getting overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `which(!is.na())` and `purrr::map`. These are good sources to learn more about the [`tidyverse`](https://github.com/LSRU/tv_course) and [`purrr`](https://github.com/cwickham/purrr-tutorial).

```r
library(tidyverse)

str(dat)
#> Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':    216 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ date  : chr  "11/11/1988" "11/12/1988" "11/13/1988" "11/14/1988" ...
#>  $ month : int  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
#>  $ day   : int  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 ...
#>  $ year  : int  1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 ...
#>  $ samp  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#>  $ precip: num  0 0 0.55 0 0 0.52 0 0 0 0.39 ...
#>  $ snow  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

# Extra: convert date from character to date format
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Find the row locations at which `samp` is not `NA`

```r
idx <- which(!is.na(dat$samp))
idx
#> [1] 111 174 203
```

Next we loop through these row indices then extract values 5 days prior to them

```r
idx %>% 
  map(. , function(x) dat[(x-5):(x), ])

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   date       month   day  year  samp precip  snow
#>   <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 1989-02-24     2    24  1989    NA     0.     0
#> 2 1989-02-25     2    25  1989    NA     0.     0
#> 3 1989-02-26     2    26  1989    NA     0.     0
#> 4 1989-02-27     2    27  1989    NA     0.     0
#> 5 1989-02-28     2    28  1989    NA     0.     0
#> 6 1989-03-01     3     1  1989     1     0.     0
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   date       month   day  year  samp precip  snow
#>   <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 1989-04-28     4    28  1989    NA  0.280     0
#> 2 1989-04-29     4    29  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 3 1989-04-30     4    30  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 4 1989-05-01     5     1  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 5 1989-05-02     5     2  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 6 1989-05-03     5     3  1989     0  0.280     0
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   date       month   day  year  samp precip  snow
#>   <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>
#> 1 1989-05-27     5    27  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 2 1989-05-28     5    28  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 3 1989-05-29     5    29  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 4 1989-05-30     5    30  1989    NA  1.50      0
#> 5 1989-05-31     5    31  1989    NA  0.140     0
#> 6 1989-06-01     6     1  1989     1  0.970     0
```

If we want the result in a data frame

```r
idx %>% 
  map_df(. , function(x) dat[(x-5):(x), ])

#> # A tibble: 18 x 7
#>    date       month   day  year  samp precip  snow
#>    <date>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1 1989-02-24     2    24  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  2 1989-02-25     2    25  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  3 1989-02-26     2    26  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  4 1989-02-27     2    27  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  5 1989-02-28     2    28  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  6 1989-03-01     3     1  1989     1  0.        0
#>  7 1989-04-28     4    28  1989    NA  0.280     0
#>  8 1989-04-29     4    29  1989    NA  0.        0
#>  9 1989-04-30     4    30  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 10 1989-05-01     5     1  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 11 1989-05-02     5     2  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 12 1989-05-03     5     3  1989     0  0.280     0
#> 13 1989-05-27     5    27  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 14 1989-05-28     5    28  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 15 1989-05-29     5    29  1989    NA  0.        0
#> 16 1989-05-30     5    30  1989    NA  1.50      0
#> 17 1989-05-31     5    31  1989    NA  0.140     0
#> 18 1989-06-01     6     1  1989     1  0.970     0
```

More compacted form where you replace `function(x) & x` with `"~" & "."`

```r
idx %>% 
  map_df(~ dat[(. -5):(.), ])
```

Created on 2018-03-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! It can be intimidating to post questions on here and feedback can be rude and belittling. Your comment was extremely helpful, I am going to study many of the things you mentioned and it is a great starting point for my statistical analysis. The break out of the sampling dates and associated days prior is exactly what I was thinking of but did not how to articulate in R. Thank you for your time and clear explanation of your solution.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry you felt that way about SO. I can understand other posters as there are hundreds of posts everyday asking for help without showing any effort or providing any reproducible data. From my own experience, you need to do your homework first to get the most out of SO. There are many knowledgeable brilliant people here.    

Anyway I recommend you to spend good amount of time going through these: [R for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)  and [R for Earth-System Science](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/index.html). Cheers!